# joomla - homepage not shown in the main menu of the website

Tags: menu, joomla

Question: I'm working on updating a website(Joomla! 1.5.18; somebody else did it and I got hired to do changes) that has a homepage already designed.  When you enter any of the sections of the website, the homepage still is part of the main menu.  I'm trying to remove that option of the menu, so the homepage can only be accessed the first time you enter de domain in the browser, and once you click to enter the website, the main menu would not give access to go back to the homepage.  That menu in particular is shown as a wrapper, but I haven't been able to see how it 'wraps up', because I try to go directly to the wrapper address and it shows me a page completely different of the actual homepage

I've tried to disable it, but because it is the designated homepage Joomla! doesn't let me unpublish it without giving me a 404 error when I enter the domain in the browser.

What can I do?

Comment: I will assume that what you want to do with your home page is like a `Splash Screen`. If that so, leave home page as it is, do some workaround to add a splash screen.

Comment: actually, this homepage I'm telling you acts like a splash screen itself.  The only thing is that it has to be part of the main menu, as far as I can see.  That's the part i want to modify somehow; I don't want that homepage to be accessed through the main menu once people enter

Comment: Please see this: http://www.pixrepublik.com.ph it has an introduction page then after entering the website, the intro will not be on the  menu. But I'm afraid you cannot prevent the "back button" to fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joomla 1.5 pulls up a specific menu item as the homepage. You can choose this menu item by going into *any* menu, tick the box beside the menu item and click on "Default" at the top right of the menu manager screen.

Therefore you do not have to have the homepage in mainmenu.

Comment: could you explain that a bit more? I didn't understood what you meant, thank you